# iOS 8 widget, sharing data between app groups forward and backward

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I've a messages app and I started to create a widget.
Updating the core data with the new messages happens when user open the app.
My wish is when:

```
- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler
```

called I will get the `UIViewController` and call the my get messages thread.
Linking the `UIViewController` against my widget target gave me an error:

```
'sharedApplication' is unavailable....
```

So I canceled it.

What I'm trying to achieve:
1. widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler is being called
2. Application start the get messages thread/method
3. when it finish, it send back data to the widget using NSUserDefaults

My code:

1:

```
- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler
{
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    [self startGetMessages];

    // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResultFailed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResultNoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResultNewData

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
}
```

2:

```
- (void)startGetMessages
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    NSBundle *deviceBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:deviceBundle];
    id MainController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTableViewController"];
    SEL getMessagesSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"startGetMessages:");

    if (MainController)
    {
        NSThread *startGetMessagesThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:MainController
                                                                   selector:getMessagesSelector
                                                                     object:StringForInt(HRTableDataSourceKindUpdate)];
        [startGetMessagesThread start];
    }
}
```

3:

```
- (void)notifyWidgetForChanges
{

    __block NSMutableDictionary *newMessages = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    NSArray *results = [CoreDataPhotoRecord MR_findAllSortedBy:@"message.originalDate"
                                                     ascending:NO
                                                 withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(message.delete_message == %@) AND (message.type.integerValue == %d) AND (message.originalDate >= %@)",
                                                                @NO, NORMAL_MESSAGE, _notiftWidgetDate]];

    NSLog(@"%s, _notiftWidgetDate: %@, newMessages.count: %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, _notiftWidgetDate, newMessages.count);

    [results enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CoreDataPhotoRecord *photoDetails, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if (photoDetails != nil && photoDetails.message != nil)
        {
            NSString *cleanMobile = [[ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] getCleanMobile:photoDetails.message.mobile];
            Contact *person = [[ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] findContactWithPhoneNumber:cleanMobile];
            ContactWidget *contact = [[ContactWidget alloc] init];
            contact.name = (person != nil && person.name != nil && person.name.length > 0) ? person.name : cleanMobile;

            [newMessages setObject:contact forKey:cleanMobile];
        }
    }];

    [SharedUtilities archiveObject:newMessages.copy forKey:MESSAGES_KEY_NEW widget:true];

    [DEFAULTS_WIDGET setObject:@"111" forKey:@"111"];
    [DEFAULTS_WIDGET synchronize];

    newMessages = nil;
    results = nil;
}

widgetDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:WIDGET_GROUP_NAME];
```

Nothing is happen since the `MainController` in step 2 is nil.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nil` problem occurs because you try to access application's storyboard from widget. It's not straightforward, since the containing app and widget extension are being kept in a separate bundles. So the `[NSBundle mainBundle]` in step 2) is not the same bundle as the one in your app.

Possible solutions include:

- including the app's `Main.storyboard` in extensions bundle either via adding it to `Copy Bundle resources` list at widget's target `Build Phases` tab or just adding widget target to `Main.storyboard` list of *Target Membership*
- moving the code responsible for getting the messages from `MainController startGetMessages:` **into a shared framework** that will be accessible both from the app and the widget, preferably into a dedicated object.

The second one is way better. As a rule of thumb it's best to follow **SOLID** principles when doing the *object-oriented* programming, where **S** stands for **single responsibility**. It should not be a responsibility of *view controller* to provide the messages fetching system-wide. Creating a dedicated object that will have only one job - to get messages - and sharing it across the targets is a way to go.

Please consult the docs for the detailed explanation on how to create the *shared framework*: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1